# Issues running spark-submit opening a SparkContext

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

firstly I describe my scenario.
Ubuntu 14.04
Spark 1.6.3
Python 3.5

I'm trying to execute my python scripts thru spark-submit. I need to create a context and then apply SQLContext as well.

Primarily I have tested a very easy case in my pyspark console:

[image]

Then I'm creating my python script.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

conf = (SparkConf()
         .setMaster("local")
         .setAppName("My app")
         .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g"))
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

numbersRDD = sc.parallelize(numbers)
numbersRDD.take(2)
```

But, when I run this in my submit-spark it is not going thru.I never get the results :(

[image]

Comment: @andres angel please do change '' result = numbersRDD.take(2) print result '' to get printed in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason you should get any "results". You script doesn't execute any obvious side effects (printing to `stdout`, writing to file), other than standard Spark logging (visible in the output). `numbersRDD.take(2)` will execute just fine.

If you want to get some form of output `print`:

```
print(numbersRDD.take(2))
```

You should also stop the context before exiting:

```
sc.stop()
```

Comment: And, optionally, reduce the console messages by setting `sc.setLogLevel("WARN")` - [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.setLogLevel)